# how to get controller name in codeigniter into controller

Tags: codeigniter-3

I need get current controller name in codiegniter for this:

```
        $control = class($id);
        if ($control = 'Usuarios'){
            $ativo['ativo'] = 'active';
        } else {
            $ativo['ativo'] = '';
        };
```

to pass $ativo to my view

Comment: A name work this... 

$control = $this->router->fetch_class();

But, if condiction no work

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing but assigning value. To compare you have to use

```
if ($control == 'Usuarios') {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

or

```
if ($control === 'Usuarios') {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).